# cluster analysis on a dataset which consist of categorical and continuous data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have never done a cluster analysis in my life before and I neatly followed the steps of one book about how to do cluster analysis in R.

*Practical Guide to Cluster Analysis in R: Unsupervised Machine Learning: Volume 1 (Multivariate Analysis) by Mr. Alboukadel Kassambara*

However I come across a problem, since in the book data standardization takes places of numeric variables, however I have got a dataset which consists of 13 variables from which the most are **categorical**. I have looked up google and some stackoverflow questions and I can't find a definte answer as how to handle cluster analysis on a combination of categorical and continuous variables. Some people mention hierarchical clustering, while some other people preach another algorithm, So I am bit at loss about which algorithym should be applied to adataset which consists of categorical and discrete variables.

Comment: I had the same issue a while back, so I discovered the function `kproto`. You may want to look at it.

Comment: Just a heads up, I flagged this for migration to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), the stats SE site. You're more likely to find help there on an algorithm to use, and it's worth checking out posts that are already over there on clustering

Comment: @akash87 Thank you very much for telling me! tried to install the package clustMixType’, however I get the following error,package ‘‘clustMixType’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0) do you know by chance which version of Rstudio is needed for the package?

Comment: I have version 3.4.4

Comment: There is no ultimate "one size fits all" solution. You should try  hierarchical clustering *and* all the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster analysis is all about distance.

You can solve your problem in a few steps:

**Step 1: Define the distance between values.**

You can get distance metrics made quickly by using `daisy()` in the `cluster` package.  This function will work for a mix of continuous and categorical variables.

**Step 2: Cluster.**

You can use a variety of algorithms with your newly formed distance matrix.  Hierarchical clustering is going to allow for a visual representation you may find useful in determining the number of clusters you'd like to argue for in your analysis.

**Example**

Example data:

```
a      b     c      d
frog   lamp  llama  7.8 
frog   onion cat    4.3
frog   lamp  soup   1.3
monkey onion  cat   8.1
dragon onion  llama  3.6
```

Code:

```
library(cluster)

#make the distance matrix
dist<-daisy(df)

#make a hierarchical cluster model
model<-hclust(dist)

#plotting the hierarchy
plot(model)

#cutting the tree at your decided level
clustmember<-cutree(model,3) 

#adding the cluster member as a column to your data
df1<-data.frame(df,cluster=clustmember)
```

Result:

```
a      b     c      d    cluster
frog   lamp  llama  7.8    1
frog   onion cat    4.3    2
frog   lamp  soup   1.3    1
monkey onion  cat   8.1    2
dragon onion  llama  3.6   3
```

Comment: thank you very much for the code, I was however wondering about a few stuff: Firstly I was wondering whether in the daisy funciton, I should add gower, since according to the daisy documentation gower is especially for categorical variables and furhtermore I was wondering who I should determine the number of cut levels in the clustmember function

Comment: Gower is chosen automatically when some columns are not numeric. It'd do no harm to add it to the code, but there's no need.  Determining the number of clusters to use can be done in several ways.  There is no "right" answer with clustering, just one that you can make a good argument for.  This site is a great resource on hierarchical clustering and methods of choosing a number of clusters: https://uc-r.github.io/hc_clustering

Comment: thanks for the link, I had an additional questoin, I before doing the clustering, should the Na values be removed?